# Many to many to many relation

Tags: database-design

I have a problem that might not be possible in a normal database without having to expand horizontally.

I have a shop, the shop contains a `Product`. For example a clothing store. As many stores you can choose between the `Color` and the `Size`. I call these for now `Types`.

The tables will look like this:

### `Product`

- `Product name`

### `ProductTypes`

- `ProductId`
- `TypeId1`
- `TypeId2`
- `Price`
- `Weight`
- `Stock`
- `Etc...`

### `Types`

- `TypeId`
- `Type name`

Not really normalized because `TypeId1` and `TypeId2` are still together in the same table. Maybe the customers wants to have 10 types assigned to a product which effectively creates a 10D matrix with all the correlations between the type, but then I would have to create 8 more `TypeId`'s to the `ProductTypes` table.

Is this properly normalizable without having to scale horizontally?

For example, I have the following types: `Color`, `Size`, `Gender` and `Shape`.

I need to be able to say that the `Blue` `XL` `Male` `Turtleneck` of the main product `shirt` has no stock, and that the price has changed. But I need to be able to dynamically add more types to a product.

Basically I am asking, how do I store a 5d array lookup in a rational database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.

Your tables should look like this.

```
Product
-------
Product ID
Product Name
Weight
Stock Number
...
```

Product ID is an auto-incrementing integer defined as the primary (clustering) key.  I'm assuming, based on your design, that weight and stock number belong with the product.  Any attributes that belong to the item and type can be moved to the ItemType table described later.

```
Type
----
Type ID
Type Name
Type Value
...
```

Type ID is an incrementing integer. Type ID and Type Value combine to be the primary (clustering) key.

In other words, (0, Size, S), (0, Size, M), etc.  You can break this into two separate tables to further normalize if you want.  It's easier to visually verify your type rows with this single table.

```
Item
----
Item ID
Product ID
SKU
Quantity On Hand
Price
...
```

Item ID is an auto-incrementing integer defined as the primary (clustering) key.  Product ID is a foreign key to the Product table. Every combination of types (every unique item) in your inventory is defined in this table.  As an example, Item ID 16 is a men's dress shirt (product), blue (type), XL (type), SKU MD-14850639.  These type attributes come together in the ItemType table.

```
ItemType
--------
Item ID
Type ID
...
```

Item ID and Type ID combine to be the primary (clustering) key.  You can have as many types for an item as you want.

Comment: Your assumption about the price is wrong about the price and stock. What if the Blue product is sold out? Or actually the Blue XL Men's shirt? Where Blue, XL and Men are all types. Where would I keep track of that?

Comment: I see what you did yes, but to make a select would be quite the challenge! I think I will go a simpler way and not normalize this all the way through to avoid the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear on what a `Product` is versus a `ProductType`. It sounds like a `Product` is a leaf category item like "Levi's 501 Jeans", `Type` is an axis like "Inseam Length", "Waist", or "Color", and `ProductType` is a particular SKU that allows you to keep track of "34Wx36L Blue" as compared to "30Wx36L Black".

You just need to create a new table `TypesToProductTypes` with a `ProductTypeId` column, a `TypeId` column, and a `Value` column. Then you can have as many TypeIds as you want per product.

So let's say we have want to represent "Levi's 501 Original" in "34Wx36L Blue" and "30Wx36L Black":

### Product

```
ProductId     Name
---------     -------------------
        1     Levi's 501 Original
```

### Type

```
TypeId     Name
------     -------------
     1     Color
     2     Waist
     3     Inseam Length
```

### ProductType

```
ProductTypeId     ProductId     Name                                  SKU#
-------------     ---------     ---------------------------------     ---------
            1             1     Levi's 501 Original 34Wx36L Blue      005011627
            2             1     Levi's 501 Original 30Wx36L Black     005011660
```

### TypesToProductTypes

```
ProductTypeId     TypeId     Value
-------------     ------     ----------
            1          1     Blue
            1          2     34
            1          3     36
            2          1     Black
            2          2     30
            2          3     36
```

I used your given table names to make the example easier to understand, but what you call `Product` I would call `CatalogItem, what you call`ProductType`I would call`SKU`, and what you call`Type`I would call`Attribute`.

Comment: And how can I then connect a price to Type1 and Type2? That's the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to know which one is `Type1` and which is `Type2`?

Comment: Like I put in my example, type1 and type2 are now hard-defined, they can exists or be null, but to introduce a `Type3` I would need to expand the table horizontally, which is bad normalization practice. Basically I need to be able to create a 3D/4D/5D/nD lookup matrix with a type on every axis. (would be a pain to configure but that's not the point).

Comment: @Rogier21: In that case, the edit I made will do what you want.

Comment: Either you don't get the question, or I don't get the answer :) But I need to store the correlation between N types. Product Shirt, Color:Blue, Size:L = price 5,00. Product Shirt Color: Blue, Size S = price 6,00. Maybe in the future I want to add a 3rd type, shape for example. Product shirt color blue, size S, shape V = price 7,00 etc.

Comment: I'm afraid your original question doesn't give a good distinction between `Product` and `ProductType` so I didn't understand it. I think I get what you're saying now, so my answer should make more sense.

Comment: And I suppose you would store the Price in ProductType?

Comment: @Rogier21: Anything associated with a specific SKU would go into `ProductType`: price, cost, shipping weight, inventory on hand, reorder level, backorder date, package quantity, dimensions, and so on.

Comment: If you only support one currency, yes. ;)

Comment: @DanMan: Yes, you can complicate things significantly. If you have multiple suppliers, you would have to store cost and backorder date separately. If you have multiple currencies, you will have to store price separately for each. If you have multiple tax jurisdictions, them whether it's taxed or the tax rate may need to be stored separately.